# Mass edit of Excel conditional format structure with formulas. Used the year 2022 in the formulas and need to change for 2023

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting, editing

I created a 17 tab worksheet for company locations to track monthly performance metrics against a budget. I used a reference cell as a condition to control conditional formatting of cells as well as normal cell value formulas. Many of these are stacked in `IF` functions for the year with multiple rules for each cell as well. The reference cell is controlled by data validation list and is simply text for the month with the year (ex. July 2022).

My problem is probably obvious now! It's 2023! When I change my data validation reference (ex July 2023) the formulas exhibit different errors and conditional formatting fails. I was able to correct the cell formulas by using the Find and Replace function but this does not edit/update the conditional formatting rules.

Here is a conditional formatting rule example: In a column for December data the Formula: `=$F$4="November 2022"` turns font to a light gray and fills the cell white. Cell F4 is changed each month the the current month. The rule is repeated in the cells for each month to determine the font color as gray for a future month or black for past or current month. I have 36 tabs with 40 rows and twelve columns using this method. The 2022 in the conditional formatting rules needs to be 2023 now.

Is there a method to update the rules en masse? Using VBA, Macro, or something else? The change would affect about 22,000 entries and manual updating is a suicide mission.

[image: Cond. Format Rule Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a VBA solution. This will change it for the active sheet:

```vb
Sub ChangeYearTo2023()
    Dim cf As FormatCondition
    For Each cf In ActiveSheet.Cells.FormatConditions
        cf.Formula1 = Replace(cf.Formula1, "2022", "2023")
    Next
End Sub
```

You could also consider changing the formulas to always work for whatever the current year is. This may or may not be a good thing for your data.

```vb
Sub ChangeYearToCurrentYear()
    Dim cf As FormatCondition
    For Each cf In ActiveSheet.Cells.FormatConditions
        cf.Formula1 = Replace(cf.Formula1, "2022""", """ & YEAR(TODAY())")
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score -2):

For future spreadsheets that YOU build (not much direct help for those someone else builds), you can always put such things into Named Ranges and use the Named Range in the Conditional Formatting formulas. Changing the Named Range's value, easy to do, would then "roll out" into all formulas that use it.

Or use the given macro to replace the 2022 with a newly created Named Range.

(Of course, now that you have the nice macro, I guess it could be the linchpin of your future creations.)

But for those who are not permitted use of macros...

Though... it IS a nice macro and macros make things so easy, one could point out that even if in an organization that does not permit macros, one need not SAVE the macro, just open the spreadsheet, paste it into a module, use it, then delete it before saving, or take care to save as an XLSX so that Excel does the stripping out for you. Might not meet the spirit of organizational rules, but you know... I would point out though, that I am in no position to replace your paychecks if "letter of the law vs. spirit of the law" isn't taken well.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).